# Boundary points of the complex plane

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

There is no boundary points of the complex plane.
Since complex plane $C$ is closed, it contains all of its boundary points.
And, since $C$ is open, it cannot contain any of its boundary points.
Then, set of all boundary points of $C$ must be empty to satisfy both conditions.
Similarly, set of all boundary points of empty set is empty set.

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

In general since $\partial A = \bar A - A^o,$
the boundary of any clopen subset, including
the empty set and the whole space, is  empty.